# Translating C# object method chaining to F#

Tags: c#, f#

Rather silly question, but I can't seem to find the correct terminology for it, so all my searching fails.

I have the following C# chain of method calls:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IMyInterface>().ImplementedBy<MyClass>().Named("MyInstance").LifeStyleSingleton);
```

How do I write the same in F#?

I can do this:

```
let f0 = Component.For<IMyInterface> () in
let f1 = f0.ImplementedBy<MyClass> () in
let f2 = f1.Named "MyInstance" in
let f3 = f2.LifestyleSingleton () in
ignore (container.Register f3)
```

But surely there must be some other, nicer way to structure such a call.  No?

**Addition**

The early answers led me to a solution that worked (I've removed all mentions of `ignore` since it irrelevant and only confused readers):

```
container.Register (Component.For<IMyInterface>().ImplementedBy<MyClass>().Named("MyInstance").LifestyleSingleton())
```

However, one reply states that this should work:

```
container.Register <| Component.For<IMyInterface>().ImplementedBy<MyClass>().Named("MyInstance").LifestyleSingleton()
```

but it doesn't.  The latter part, the expression after `<|`, generates a type error

> This expression was expected to have type unit but here has type ComponentRegistration<IMyInterface>.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can write it exactly the same as C# version with `|> ignore` at the very end; you'd have to test it though.

Comment: A side note, you generally don't need full `let .. in` unless your `let` and the expression you use it are in a single line, you can just do `let`.

Answer (score 6):

You can do pretty much the same thing in F#:

```
container.Register <|
    Component
        .For<IMyInterface>()
        .ImplementedBy<MyClass>()
        .Named("My Instance")
        .LifeStyleSingleton()
```

Here with some added sugar (`<|`). You can put the calls on a single line, or like I just did (I prefer that, since it nicely mirrors F# pipelining). One thing to remember is that the arguments need to be parenthesised and with no spaces between function name and the parens (pretty much "C# style").

Comment: I don't seems to be able to.  The line `container.Register <| Component.For<IMyInterface>().ImplementedBy<MyClass>().Named("MyInstance").LifestyleSingleton()` results in a `This expression was expected to have type unit but has type ComponentRegistration<IMyInterface>`.  That's likely related to the CastleWindsor method `container.Register`.  On the other hand, your comment about spaces led me to find that `container.Register (Component.For<IMyInterface>().ImplementedBy<IMyClass>().Named("MyInstance").LifestyleSingleton())` worked all right.

Comment: Well, F# makes you deliberately ignore unused values--end your statement with `|> ignore` to do so.

Comment: Oh, I need to clarify that, it's the expression `Component.For<IMyInterface>().ImplementedBy<MyClass>().Named("MyInstance").Lifes‌​tyleSingleton()` that generates the type error when I use `<|`.  That is, `f x` type checks, but `f <| x` doesn't.

Comment: @Magnus: I don't think this would be the case - ignore(f <| x) should type check for you.

Comment: @scrwtp, I agree, it shouldn't be the case.  I've taken a [screenshot](https://db.tt/KGy4skZs) of it.

Comment: @Magnus: Perhaps F# is confused by Register having multiple overloads and/or optional arguments. Hard to tell without looking at CastleWindsor itself. In worst case you just have to go with the parens.